# Is there a way to enforce unique constraint on a composite GSI in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

In DynamodDB i want to enforce uniqueness based on GSI (Hash & Range). Is it possible using DynamoDBSaveExpression or by any other mean?

I want my create function to fail if the Expected GSI hash and range both are matching.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is not.

However, you can simulate it by creating a second table instead of creating a GSI, and then using DynamoDB transactions every time you write to update both tables atomically.